# Canonical Correlation Definitions

Tags: canonical-correlation

Suppose that we have two sets of variables $\textbf{X}$ and $\textbf{Y}$. Let $$ \textbf{X} = \begin{pmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2\\ \vdots \\X_p \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$ \textbf{Y} = \begin{pmatrix} Y_1 \\ Y_2\\ \vdots \\Y_q \end{pmatrix}$$

where $p \leq q$.

Define the following linear combinations: $$U_i = a_{i1}X_1 + a_{i2}X_2 + \cdots + a_{ip}X_p$$ $$V_i = b_{i1}Y_1 + b_{i2}Y_2 + \cdots + b_{iq}Y_q$$

Does it matter what we call the first canonical variate pair? For example is the first canonical variate pair $(U_1, V_1)$? Or would we define the first canonical variate pair as $(U_1, V_3)$?

Comment: (1) There is something wrong with your formula. What $a_i$ might be and why both expressions end up at $p$? (2) The first canonical variate pair is U1,V1. Correlation between them is the 1st canonical correlation.

Comment: @ttnphns: But wht is the difference between $(U_1,V_1)$ and $(U_1, V_2)$? Couldn't we just call $V_2$ $V_1$?